# Can this function be decomposed into an even function in the real part and an odd function in the imaginary part

Tags: functional-analysis, real-analysis, complex-analysis

There is a function that like

> $\frac{1}{\eta}e^{-s(px+\eta z)}$

in this function, $\eta=\sqrt{(\frac{1}{\beta^2})-p^2}$,and $Re(\eta)\ge0$

$x, z, \beta$ are real numbers, $p$ is a complex number, $s$ is the laplace transform parameter, and $s=ikp$, $k$ is the fourier transform parameter.

Can this function be decomposed into an even function in the real part and an odd function in the imaginary part with respect to $p$?

Comment: Could you please clarify which is the function variable?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to  clarify this function's variable, the function variable is $p$

Comment: If $p$ can be complex, the answer is clearly no. Just consider purely imaginary $p=ip'$ with real $p'$. Then both real and imaginary part are of the form $(even) \exp [(even) p']$.

Comment: I also don't understand why this function $-s(px+\eta z)$ is an even function. When just consider purely imaginary $p =ip^{'}$ with real $p^{'}$, $-s(px+\eta z)=-s(ip^{'}x+\eta z)$. When p takes the opposite number， $p=-ip^{'}$, $-s(px+\eta z)=-s(-ip^{'}x+\eta z)$.  the function $-s(px+\eta z)$ isn't an even function

Comment: You indicate $\eta=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\beta^2}-p^2}$ and $s=i k p$, so shouldn't you really be considering $-s (p x+\eta z)=-i k p \left(p x+z \sqrt{\frac{1}{\beta^2}-p^2}\right)$?

Comment: However, Can this function $\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1/\beta^2-p^2}}e^{-ikp(px+z\sqrt{1/\beta^2-p^2})} \  $ be decomposed into an even function in the real part and an odd function in the imaginary part with respect to $p$?